# Check if web browser control load on other form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a application in Visual Studio using WinForms and C#.

The application has two forms where one is visible on start. On start the other (hidden) form starts navigation on a WebBrowser component, and when it is loaded it should hide the first form and show the one with the browser.

I am not sure on how to check if the form is done or not. However I have found that one can use:

```
if (browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
```

But I do not know how make the forms communicate.

Comment: What do you exactly have a problem with?

Comment: i want check in form 2 if web browser that there in form 1 is loaded,close form 2 and show form 1 and web browser

Comment: @developerweb i rewrote the question (some time ago), did it lose anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the form with your web browser make a public method:

```
    public bool IsWebBrowserReady
    {
        get { return browser.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete; }    
    }
```

Then something like this in your Main:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Initialize forms
    var browserForm = new Form1();
    var startForm = new StartForm();

    //Show first form
    startForm.Show();

    //Make sure second form is not visible
    browserForm.WindowState=FormWindowState.Minimized;
    browserForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;

    //"Show" second form
    browserForm.Show();

    //Wait for it to be ready
    while (!browserForm.IsWebBrowserReady) Application.DoEvents();

    //Hide first form
    startForm.Hide();

    //Show second form
    browserForm.ShowInTaskbar = true;
    browserForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

    Application.Run();
}
```

Or you can move some of this logic into the StartForm, by passing a reference of the second form into it. Then you can access the IsWebBrowserReady from the first form. But if this is just a splashscreen solution you are making I would say that would be overkill.

As an alternative to polling the status of the web browser one can also react to the web browsers OnDocumentCompleted. It would be a different pattern but look at Zombies answer to get an idea.

Comment: Do you think a `Application.DoEvents()` loop is better than the `OnDocumentCompleted ` event ?

Comment: Not really, it is just another way to do it. DoEvents is mostly frowned upon :), but using it is Main() is pretty OK in my eyes.

Comment: do you think you can add the `OnDocumentCompleted` (either replace your `Application.DoEvents()`, or mention it as an alternative)? Your answer is nicer than mine, so if you mention the `OnDocumentCompleted` i can remove my answer.

Comment: Don't remove it. Its a different solution to the same problem.

Comment: but then i need to improve it (i am not really satisfied with it), and I would end up with a too similar answer to yours. I would prefer that you include the actual code, and that i remove my answer. I think it is the best solution for SO.

Answer (score 1):

The WebBrowser have a nice little event called [OnDocumentCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.ondocumentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can listen on. It fires when the page is loaded.

```
Form form2 = new Form2();
form2.webBrowser1.OnDocumentCompleted += (e, sender) =>
{
  if (form2.webBrowser1.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) // each frame trigger the event (?), make sure all is done
  {
    form2.show();
    hide();
  }
};
form2.webBrowser.Navigate("{url}");
```

(The code is not tested, and might not be correct, but it should give you and idea on what you can test)

Might need to be public, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31109442/1938640).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, try this.
It's not the best solution, but it does the job.

- Make sure the WebBrowserControl has it's members set to "public", this way you'll be able to access the control's members from another form. (In other words, the control will have the access modifier set to "public": read more at https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)
- Then new up form1 from form2 (or make sure that form2 has a variable containing a reference to form1). This way you'll be able to manipulate or query form1 from form2.

As I said, not the most elegant solution, but it's the quickest way to get it done for now.